# Can a Constructor Use a Builder

Tags: java, constructor, refactoring, builder

I am refactoring a class to use a builder with a private constructor instead of public constructors. I want to have the old, deprecated, public constructors use the builder as shown below. *(this is an example of the behavior I am try to achieve)*

```
// old public construcor
@Deprecated
public MyClazz(){
    return new MyClazzBuilder().Build();
}
```

This give a "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type"

Is this type of functionality possible in Java? How could this be achieved?

***Update:** This code is part of a distributed jar, deleting the old constructors is not an option because I need to maintain backwards compatibility*

Comment: how do you think that constructor would return something? it cannot be achieved. Only a method can return something in Java.

Comment: @harsh The code is to demonstrate the behavior I am trying to achieve.

Comment: for how long do you need to be backwards compatible?

Comment: @Woot4Moo until all projects that use the call have been updated, so probably a while. > 1 year

Comment: You are inmplementing it incorrectly. Check [Wiki Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with example in Java

Comment: I see.  Yeah I would just leave the old constructor invocations there with the old implementation.  Deprecate and force all new code to use this.

Comment: That example does not take immutability into account, see [immutability-with-builder-design-pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/immutability-with-builder-design-pattern) for a different implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Constructors operate on an object, they don't return it. [footnote 1]

One way to get this sort of functionality is with an `init()` method.

```
@Deprecated
public MyClazz() {
  init();
}

public void init() {
  // do the actual work
}
```

Now your builder can call the same `init()` method to avoid having the code in two places.

Because you are keeping the deprecated signatures around, it's hard to avoid splitting the logic for preparing an instance into multiple places.  That's not ideal, but it's the price of deprecation and maintaining backwards compatibility.

[footnote 1] The lifecycle of a java object is that first the object memory is allocated, but all the fields have junk content.  Next a constructor is run on the memory to get it into a consistent state by changing all those meaningless values into real values.  Note that the memory the constructor works on is already there, so you can never substitute another object in place of the one being constructed.  A return value from a constructor would be exactly this sort of substitution, which is not supported by the language.  If that trick is needed use a factory/builder instead of a constructor -- constructors can never do that.

Comment: hmm, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Does this clear things up?  If not, I need a more specific question.

Comment: You stated constructors operate on an object, just wondering if you could clarify that.  I presume you are talking about space allocation and such, but other readers may not.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors don't return values.  Notice how there is no "declared" return type in a constructor signature.  You have a few options:

1)  Mark the constructor private and resolve compilation errors immediately
2)  Deprecate the constructor, and leave the original implementation there.

I recommend number 2.  What you have done is deprecate a constructor, and then changed the implementation.  That is not how deprecation works.